# Laravel Doesn't Render Images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have setup a site using Laravel version 6.0.3 on my local machine.

I ran this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And have uploaded an image file 'black.png' to my site.

The upload works well and the file exists relative to root at:

storage/app/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png

However when I use the assets function

```
$image = "posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png";
assets($image);
```

It outputs the following link to the image:

```
http://cms.test/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png
```

Which doesn't give a 404 error. And when visited is a blank page.

What could I be missing?

EDIT:

If I try to use:

```
{{ asset('storage/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png') }}
```

Then when I load the page I get a 404 error for the image at URL:

```
 http://cms.test/storage/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png
```

Similarly, if I try:

```
{{ asset('storage/app/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png') }}
```

I also get a 404 error for the URL:
     http://cms.test/storage/app/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png

Response in network debug window after returning to initial code:

```
$image = "posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png";
assets($image);
```

Shows a 200 status response code from the asset.

[image]

FINAL EDIT:

Following ceejayoz' instruction, I made two crucial tweaks. First inside of config/filesystems.php I changed one of the local variables:

```
'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
```

And in my template call I used:

```
{{ asset('storage/' . $image) }}"
```

And now it works.

Comment: try to add `storage` first like this `storage/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png`

Comment: Hey Joseph. Thank you for your input. I went ahead and tried playing around with the URL but was unable to see the images still. Please see my edited question for more details.

Comment: @JackRobson, include the version of Laravel you are using in your tags.

Comment: What is the response headers for http://cms.test/posts/KiL8ZKWQIq3CK8ecd4CDVZHACFHlUsMAyq8h0AJj.png request?

Comment: @UdoE. I have added the version tags. I'm running 6.0.3.

Comment: @Constantine They are returning the status code 200. See screenshot in question.

Comment: `storage:link`, per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem), creates "a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`". Nothing in `storage/app/posts` is accessible via the link.

Comment: @JackRobson on the screenshot image has content encoding text/html...

Comment: @ceejayoz what would you suggest to try?

Comment: @Constantine any ideas why that's the case?

Comment: @JackRobson Put your files in the right spot. Put them in something like `storage/app/public/posts` when you upload them.

Comment: I think the response is "Not found" but with the wrong code 200. Anyway, look at @ceejayoz comment. I think that is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php artisan storage:link` creates a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

This makes anything in `storage/app/public` available at `https://example.com/storage/`. It doesn't make anything **outside** `storage/app/public` available anywhere - so the content in your `storage/app/posts` is still inaccessible in the browser.

If you put your post images in `storage/app/public/posts`, they'll be accessible by doing `asset('storage/posts/foo.jpg')` if you have the link set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Using your advice I was able to tweak my code to get it working. For anyone interested, see final edit of my original post.